# Input box in Widget not working WordPress

Tags: wordpress, input, widget

I am working on a plugin for countdown timer for WordPress. Found a tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-ajax-countdown-timer-wordpress-plugin--wp-25591)

have implemented everything stepwise. but the input box in the Timer Widget does not allow to input date, hours, time. So basically, this is not working.

```
<a class="tp-time-edit" href="javascript:void(0);">[ Edit ]</a><br/><br/>
<label>Select a date:</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="tp-date" class="tp-date" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $tp_arr['tp-date']; ?>"></input>
<p><div class="tp-time"><label>Hours</label>
    <input name="tp-hour-val" class="tp-hour-val" value="<?php echo $tp_arr['tp-hour']; ?>" readonly="true"></input><div class="tp-hour"></div>
</p>
<p><label>Minutes</label>  
<input name="tp-minute-val" class="tp-minute-val" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $tp_arr['tp-minute']; ?>"></input><div class="tp-minute"></div></div></p>
<input type="hidden" name="tp-hidd" value="true" />
<input type="button" class="tp-insert-shortcode button-primary" id="publish" value="Insert Short-Code" />
```

this is the code which displays the input boxes in the text widget. M not able to figure out whts wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i check the tutorial link . there is nothing wrong with the sample code that u provide
you have to check first do you really get the value of those PHP variables
i.e

```html
    <?php echo $tp_arr['tp-date']; ?>
<?php echo $tp_arr['tp-hour']; ?>
<?php echo $tp_arr['tp-minute']; ?>
```

First of all check those variables ???